# VBA code to move a textbox from one frame to another frame in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox TB1 in Frame1. In certain conditions TB1 should be visible in Frame1 and in certain condition TB1 should be visible in another frame Frame2.
Is it possible? If yes, then how ? sample coding will be appreciated :)

Comment: `Is it possible? ` Yes it is possible.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: Definitely. :) But first can you show me what have you tried and what do you feel should be the logic of the code? If you are getting any error messages then do share the error number, error message and the line which is giving you the error.

Comment: Well Two frames are there Frame1 and Frame2. Initially Frame1 has a Label1 with Caption A and Textbox TB1. Now there's a Commandbutton1. If you click the Commandbutton then TB1 shifted from Frame1 to Frame2. I dont know the coding for it..seeking help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controls that you add to Frames during design time, can not be removed programatically. Only those that are created at run-time can be added or removed during run-time.

But if you want to create a text box, dynamically, and move it between frames, here is how to do it:

1- Create a new Form in Excel VB6 interface, and add two frames on it like this:

[image: Step 1]

2- Add two buttons as shown above

3- The code for button 1 and 2 is very similar, here it is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
        Frame2.Controls.Remove ("TB2") 'Remove if TextBox already exist elsewhere
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set txt = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TB2", True)

    txt.Left = 20
    txt.Top = 20



End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


    On Error Resume Next
        Frame1.Controls.Remove ("TB2") 
    On Error GoTo 0


    Set txt = Frame2.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TB2", True)

    txt.Left = 20
    txt.Top = 20

End Sub
```

Now when you run the form, you click on button1 and the textbox is created in Frame1
Click button 2 and the textbox is removed from frame1 and created in frame2

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad. It worked.. however I have to modify the code coz initially a textbox should be in a Frame..after that I need to move. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: I have one question. In this form initially there's no textbox. once we click the command button then only a text box appears in frame. how about a textbox is already there in Frame1 and that particular textbox we want to move to frame2. which part of your code shall I modify

Comment: this is not move, but erase and copy, wich obviously wouldn't move any code attached to the control.